# EKRecurrenceRule (xcode iOS calendar interaction - Phonegap Plugin): Help creating a fairly complex event pattern

Tags: ios, cordova, calendar

I've successfully modified the Calendar.m and Calendar.h plugins for iPhone to create a fairly complex event:

In a given month, 
3 weeks have one event every 7 days, 
and the last week of the month has nothing happening.

This worked until I realized 2 things:
1. It's a given month *from the start date*. The start date can be anywhere in the month, middle or end or beginning.
2. All months don't necessarily have 28 days. I have to account for 29, 30, 31.
3. The end date, like the start date, isn't necessarily from the start of the month or end of the month either.

My EKRecurrenceRule statement:

```
EKRecurrenceRule* rrule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly
interval:1
daysOfTheWeek:nil
daysOfTheMonth:validDays monthsOfTheYear:nil weeksOfTheYear:nil daysOfTheYear:nil setPositions:nil end:rend];
```

My validDays array (suppled in daysOfTheMonth, above)

```
//Note: 22 is week 4. This will be excluded. 
validDays = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
[NSNumber numberWithInt:8],
[NSNumber numberWithInt:15],
[NSNumber numberWithInt:29], nil];
```

EKAlarm btw is at 0 offset for convenience.

Yeah, its pretty hardcoded, for now. I know I have to change the validDays array, and I know how to get day number the current day, but I don't know where to go from here. The documentation for EKRecurrenceRule doesn't seem to cover cases of complication outside of ones that start from the beginning of a month and ends at the end of a month.

Changing the start date and end dates, at least in iOS7, don't seem to make any offsets automatic. If I start on the 10th of the month, f'rex, the first reminder is on the 15th (8th and 1st have passed) - when I want the first reminder on the 17th. The first reminder should be 7 days from the start date, and every reminder subsequently 7 days after, with a 1 week break every 3 weeks.

I am currently under the impression that to account for starting in the middle of a month and for unequal month lengths, I would likely have to create multiple EKRecurrenceRules, and by extension multiple weekly or even monthly events that don't count as repeating events. This is not the desired outcome as such events are a pain to remove in the calendar.

Any help?

Comment: Uh... ok, I definitely need an answer for this. Adding individual days over a loop takes bloody ages and is not suitable for distribution. (5 minutes for a year's duration of variable dates, even if done inside the Calendar.m instead of Calendar.js. )

Comment: Nobody? I guess EKRecurrence isn't as developed as I thought it was. I'm going to have to come to the conclusion that taking into account starting from the middle of the month is patently undoable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third time answering my own question in this place.

**Edit: I realize that this event sequence is for a series of events that is 21 days/month starting from an arbitrary location in a month, until the end date. I'll tweak the code later to match the question, but this solution is related to answering the question, inclusive of limitations.**

The following is only valid for a maximum of 1 year. If you decide to use this for more than 1 year, good luck, I really cannot calculate something like that especially considering leap years.

```
  NSMutableArray *validDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSMutableArray *ignoreDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   //according to this algorithm, I only have 28 days a month. Even if a month has 31 or       30 or 29 days. This is because the schedule is counted by WEEK.
  NSInteger currday = 1;

  //excludeWeek denotes the week of a given month that I'll exclude, eg: 1 is the first week, 4 is the last week. This allows me to exclude any week of a given 28-day cycle. 

  switch (excludeWeek)
  {

      case 1:
         for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 7; ++i)
         {
            [ignoreDays addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
         }
       break;

       case 2:
         for (NSInteger i = 8; i <= 14; ++i)
         {
            [ignoreDays addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
         }

       break;

       case 3:
         for (NSInteger i = 15; i <= 21; ++i)
         {
             [ignoreDays addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
         }

         break;

       default: //or case 4:

         for (NSInteger i = 22; i <= 28; ++i)
         {
             [ignoreDays addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
         }
         break; 
     }

     //this line here is why I can only guarantee results of 1 year. Anything more and endDay may very well be 1 day after startday. I'm using day of year, the only possible values are 1-365 or -1 to -365, +-1 for leap years. 
     if (startDay == endDay) endDay -= 1;

     while (startDay != endDay)
     {

         ++startDay;

         if (isLeapYear)
         {
              //Feb has 1 more day remember?
              if (startDay > 366) startDay = 1;
         }
         else
         {
              if (startDay > 365) startDay = 1;
         }


         if ([ignoreDays containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:currday] ] == FALSE)

             [validDays addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:startDay]];

         ++currday;
         if (currday > 28) currday = 1;
   }

   EKRecurrenceRule* rrule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc]     initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyYearly
   interval:1
   daysOfTheWeek:nil
   daysOfTheMonth:nil 
   monthsOfTheYear:nil 
   weeksOfTheYear:nil 
   daysOfTheYear:[NSArray arrayWithArray:validDays] 
   setPositions:nil end:rend];
```

Hopefully anyone doesn't need a complicated sequence that lasts longer than a year. With this method you should know how to populate weeks of the year in the same way.

This still triggers the please run in separate thread warning but its much faster than doing it manually.